# Change DateTime string into Date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DateTime column, which (because of some reasons) has changed my DateTime values from DateTime to Strings. Now I want to change them back to Date only. How to do this?

e.g my date column has values like: `"Sep 2, 2019 8:00:00 PM"` (in string format)

```
select str_to_date('Date','%d-%m-%Y') as Date
  from table
```

This code gives blank cells as a result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date's format is: `'%b %e, %Y %h:%i:%s %p'`.
Read more about the parameters you can use in `str_to_date()` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp).
So do the conversion like this:

```
select str_to_date(
  'Sep 2, 2019 8:00:00 PM',
  '%b %e, %Y %h:%i:%s %p'
) as Date
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/evkXULEMENmAFQzmb2G8Ty/0).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If I want to extract only date from a datetime column, would I do the same thing?

Comment: Change to: `select date(str_to_date(
  'Sep 2, 2019 8:00:00 PM',
  '%b %e, %Y %h:%i:%s %p'
)) as Date `

Comment: it gives blank cells

Comment: Did you check the demo? It works if the format of the date is what you posted in your question.

Comment: See this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/evkXULEMENmAFQzmb2G8Ty/1 for only the date part.

Comment: Yeah I think the problem is that my date column is datetime. So the str_to_text does not work

Comment: It is str_to_date not str_to_text. If your column is datetime then all you need is the function date(): `select date(columnname).....`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the CONVERT function?

```
SELECT CONVERT(table.Date, DATE) AS Date FROM table;
```

Comment: This will not work unless `table.date` is an acceptable format for MySQL date (or datetime).